# Validating JavaScript datetimeZone format

Tags: javascript

I can validate the format of this dates using moment library:

```
2022-03-26T14:15:51 ("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
2022-03-26 ("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

But having problem with following :

```
2022-03-26T14:15:51.667778+03:00  ("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ") - this format not solving the problem.
```

Is there any solution? Maybe using regex will solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ`, I'd also suggest using strict mode when parsing dates. This format will allow a variable amount of digits after the decimal point but will refuse to parse a date with no fractional seconds:

```js
function validateDate(input, format) {
    const dt = moment(input, format, true);
    return dt.isValid();
}

const testInputs = [
    '2022-03-26T14:15:51.667778+03:00',
    '2022-03-26T14:15:51.667+03:00',
    '2022-03-26T14:15:51+03:00',
    '2022-03-26T14:15:51',
    'FOO'
]

const format = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ';

console.log('Input'.padEnd(36), 'Valid');
testInputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.padEnd(36), validateDate(input, format)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```